# Counting number of words that contain a substring with grep

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I am trying to grep a file for the words that contain "owner" but not the word owner itself. So, "ownership" for example would be counted.

I know:

```
grep -o -c owner  #Print only matched words.  ship(owner)ship --> owner

grep -w -c owner #Match only whole words. ownership (No), owner (Yes)
```

But it returns the whole standalone word "owner" still.

Whats the correct way to do this?

Comment: Does `grep -o -c owner` catch "owner" and derivative words, like "ownership"? If yes, subtract the number of word obtained from your second line and you are done, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
grep -Pc '(\wowner)|(owner\w)' file
```

the word should have either a prefix or suffix (so the standalone won't match).  Note that this will count the number of lines that have a match.  To count the occurances

```
grep -oP '(\wowner)|(owner\w)' file | wc -l
```

Comment: thanks this worked. May I ask what the P flag does?